# Communicate child-view and master-view in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one custom view, a directive in which I want to send the value to the master view, which is a component. I am newbie in TypeScript, and I have viewed many examples but, they were when a user clicks on somewhere to trigger the event of emitting the value to other components or services. I am wonder how can I read a value and send it, while typing in `textarea` component for example.
Thanks for helps

`**text-area.component.html**`

```
<textarea #inputField (ngModelChange)="onValueChanged($event)" [@slideInOut]="textAreaOpen"
          [ngClass]="{'tweet-box-shadow': true, 'hidden': this.openTextArea === false ? 'hidden' : ''}"
          aria-hidden="true" autofocus></textarea>
```

`text-area.component.ts`

```
 @ViewChild('inputField')
  inputField: any;

  textAreaOpen: string = 'in';


  @Output() voted = new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        for (let propName in changes) {
          let change = changes[propName];

          let curVal = JSON.stringify(change.currentValue);
          let prevVal = JSON.stringify(change.previousValue);
          let changeLog = `${propName}: currentValue = ${curVal}, previousValue = ${prevVal}`;
          console.log(changeLog);
        }
        //this.voted.emit(changes);
      }

      onValueChanged(value: string) {
        console.log(value);
      }
```

Comment: In order to get help post what have you done so far

Comment: I made changes to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit value in a keyup event. In your child component template

```
<textarea #inputField (keyup)="onValueChanged(inputField.value)" [@slideInOut]="textAreaOpen"
      [ngClass]="{'tweet-box-shadow': true, 'hidden': this.openTextArea === false ? 'hidden' : ''}"
      aria-hidden="true" autofocus></textarea>
```

In you child-component.ts

```
@Output() someProp = new EventEmitter();

  onValueChanged(e) {
   // console.log(e)
   this.someProp.emit(e);
  }
```

Parent-component template

```
<child-component (someProp)="displayValue($event)"></child-component>
```

Parent-component.ts

```
displayValue(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```